# Correct way to pass between 5,000 to 100,000 values in mysql WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am getting 45000 values from one query result, and need to use this values to make second query but because of large size of array, its taking long time more than 30 seconds to execute so getting Error:

> Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Is there any other way to do this database data calculation quickly, or i should calculate the data and save it in another table to show at anytime

Queries :

```
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT DISTINCT(u.username) as mobile FROM sessionTable u WHERE u.accesspoint IN (?1) ');
    $query->setParameter(1, $accesspoint);
    $result = $query->getResult();
    $count = count($result);
    $i = 0;
    $numbers = array();
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        $numbers[$i] = $value['mobile'];
        $i++;
    }

    dump(count($numbers)); //---->  Output is 48567 --successful

    $Users = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeDataBundle:User')
            ->findByNumber($numbers);

    ----Error Occurs Here------

    dump(count($Users));
    die();
```

I am using symfony 2.0 framework , doctrine 2.0

UPDATE :
consider I have 5 tables in same database,
viz. 1- user 2- googleData 3- facebook data 4-yahooData 5- sessions

when users login to my application, I collect there gender info from either one or multiple social profile data, and save in that particular table

Now I want to calculate all users male:female ratio who have used multiple sessions,

For this scenario its going too tough to calculate male :female ratio from multiple tables. 
I feel there is one solution it will be easy if I adds Gender column directly in session table but is there any other better way by using FK or anything else ?

Comment: Split array into chunks and execute multiple queries.

Comment: or try `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes`

Comment: Noted your update, but I am sorry sorry to say it makes the question  unclear rather than clearer. Please add show create table output and a few rows of sample data if you don't mind

Answer (score 7):

If you are having to pass 1000 values never mind 100,000 values, that probably means you have a problem in the design of your queries. The data has to come from somewhere, if it's from the database, it would be a simple matter to use a join or a sub query. If it's from an external source, it can go into a temporary table.

so in short: Yes, a temporary or permanent table is better

Comment: consider i have 4 tables in same database,

Comment: If you are not satisfied with this, what you should be doing is to update your question to post your tables and also explain where your 100,000 items come from

Comment: Yes, i have updated my question, and Thank you for all suggestions

Comment: I have tried a quick test query passing parameters (8 characters long string). The max I could get pdo to handle was 2000, then it cries and dies.

Comment: Thanks @Rooneyl for the input. Building that query probably takes a bit of time too