# Optimise mysql where, group by, scanning too many rows

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

Table representing statuses. User can re-share a status as on FB, therefore the original_id.

```
| user_status | CREATE TABLE `user_status` (
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `destination_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `original_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`status_id`),
  KEY `IDX_1E527E21A76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_1E527E21C957ECED` (`destination_user_id`),
  KEY `core_index` (`destination_user_id`,`original_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1E527E21A76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1E527E21C957ECED` FOREIGN KEY (`destination_user_id`)REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=161362 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

I am trying to optimise a query for newsfeed (I removed everything unnecessary just to be able to optimise the core of the query but it's still simply slow).

Query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT MAX(us.status_id)
    FROM user_status us 
    WHERE us.destination_user_id IN (25,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,42,43,44,46,49,50,51,52,53,55,56,57,58,59,60,62,64,66,68,74,78,79,81,88,91,92,94,96,98,99,100,101,102,106,110,112,113,114,117,124,128,129,133,138,140,144,149,150,151,154,155,156,158,159,160,164,170,174,175,180,184,186,187,210,211,222,225,227,228,231,234,235,236,237,240,264,269,271,276,282,287,289,295,297,298,301,302,311,315,318,322,326,328,345,350,379,396,398,403,404,418,426,428,431,449,460,471,476,477,495,496,506,538,539,540,542,546,551,554,557,559,561,564,571,572,575,585,586,588,590,616,617,624,629,630,641,645,649,654,655,656,657,658,659,660,662,663,673,685,690,693,696,698,724,728,734,737,746,757,760,762,769,791,797,808,829,833,841,857,858,865,878,879,881,888,889,898,919,921,932,937,944,949,950,958,961,965,966,974,980,986,994,996,1005,1012,1013,1019,1020,1027,1044,1062,1079,1081,1097,1121,1122,1131,1140,1174,1178,1199,1214,1219,1221,1259,1261,1262,1268,1277,1282,1294,1300,1307,1320,1330,1331,1333,1336,1350,1361,1371,1388,1393,1440,1464,1482,1497,1507,1509,1511,1513,1514,1525,1537,1558,1569,1572,1573,1577,1584,1588,1591,1593,1627,1644,1645,1666,1688,1716,1729,1735,1751,1756,1803,1818,1828,1867,1871,1876,1914,1935,2038,2047,2058,2072,2074,2085,2106,2153,2168,2197,2232,2279,2355,2359,2511,2560,2651,2773,2803,2812,2818,2829,2835,2841,2865,2891,3032,3051,3095,3100,3148,3412,3476,3578,3623,3808,3853,3968,3976,3992,4045,4047,4069,4077,4119,4156,4237,4271,4280,4285,4337,4348,4644,4711,4872,4898,5084,5108,5110,5248,5254,5266,5268,5315,5318,5553,5716,5744,5768,5782,5784,5794,5815,5883,5920,5921,5985,5987,6016,6070,6364,7067,7522,7571,7733,7800,8259,8421,8640,9743,10039,11900,12344,12794,13419,13468,13548,13778,13829,13892,13902,13910,13976,13977,14042,14056,14171,14175,14176,14210,14255,14258,14279,14301,14343,14394,14465,14501,14538,14650,14656,14657,14805,14807,14813,14970,14975,15110,15174,15277,15284,15306,15354,15404,15649,15710,15776,16084,16099,14752,16516,1130,9770,1127,14200,13950,15842,16406,15614,16566,16209,16672,13887,16122,14857,16877,10093,15752,16131,17618,17767,5783,17867,16081,18224,6972,14273,18471,15403,16261,6641,18669,15153,18708,18534,17447,18843,18840,27,61,18656,18336,18006,15337,17197,18999,14360,19023,19002,16856,2885,17237,16560,15575,16297,11199,17836,14313,759,18403,19421,19514,2828,14562,1792,18131,19703,1280,18314,15944,17078,18316,19695,20017,16493,19566,17028,19104,17518,2045,16312,15508,20092,5060,18207,1773,17129,17154,18786,17077,15155,17640,2845,19480,20943,107,2775,21247,3989,20292,19077,20046,18230,18241,18102,19225,
         14230,21011,5765,15344,21732,11249,15532,14105,4136,17373,14612,17944,17040,15505,17528,20461,22200,14059,11701,19410,3085,12180,22730,22631,17673,2820,20826,21895,23992,24080,24249,25144,25146,25171,25177,25181,25222,25223,25232,25245,25248,25250,25252,25255,25264,25267,25276,25279,25280,25284,25294,25298,25300,25312,25324,25332,25359,25373,25374,25381,25402,25412,25430,25434,25437,25442,25444,25446,25454,25465,25474,25486,25490,25491,25494,25535,25540,25549,25555,25568,25671,25711,25713,25714,25722,25737,25755,25768,25774,
         25783,25784,25839,25854,25886,25889,25891,25913,25926,25956,25967,26026,26043) 
    GROUP BY us.original_id
    ORDER BY us.status_id DESC
    LIMIT 0,10;
```

Explain of the query:

[image]

Execution time: 10 rows in set (0,41 sec), MySQL 5.7 (strict mode turned off)

Imo. a table as small as 100k rows should be performing much better. I tried to change the indexes up and down but they seems to be properly set.

Any idea how could I optimise this query to 0.0x or 0.1x ?

**Update**

The linked duplicate is not related with my issue, shouldn't be linked imo.

Removing the unnecessary extra join resolved the issue.

[image]

Now it works as suppose to by using tight index scan http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html

I can't get rid of the "Using temporary; Using filesort" even if I change the ORDER BY to "us.original_id" but the execution time is now as expected: **0.08**

Comment: Please post the explain output as formatted text we also need the information in de Extra column

Comment: @RaymondNijland the information is there already

Comment: Where do the IN arguments come from

Comment: @Strawberry I have a table called "friends" storing the IDs of users I follow in a denormalized way as a big string in order to be able to do a micro select everytime I need the list for a specific user.

Comment: What are the indexes that you have?

Comment: I think you've just answered your own question

Comment: would u mind to explain why that would be an issue? I am submitting those values to the query directly from memory otherwise I would have to complicate the query with even more joins to retrieve this information.

Comment: What is the output of `select count(*) from user_status where destination_user_id in ($your_list_of_ids)` ?

Comment: Why are you joining to the other two tables, but not touching any columns?  If you stripped down the query, _don't_; we can only give you a stripped down answer.

Comment: what makes you think that additional joins will make things slower?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to pass between 5,000 to 100,000 values in mysql WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659553/correct-way-to-pass-between-5-000-to-100-000-values-in-mysql-where-clause)

Comment: @SashaPachev 45320 is the number of rows.

Comment: @RickJames yes ofc I can remove those joins I left them as I will use them in other cases but sure for this one I can remove it but it won't change the performance anyway. I am going to check the 5k-100k issue.

Comment: There are lots of ways additional unnecessary joins could confuse the optimizer. You should always write the query the simplest way possible and not rely on the optimizer removing what is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the two extra tables, since `us` seems to be the only one relevant.

It is not valid to `ORDER BY status_id` since it is not in the `GROUP BY`, nor (technically) in the `SELECT`..

Comment: `GROUP BY x ORDER BY y` (where `x` and `y` are different) necessarily leads to a tmp table and filesort for the `ORDER BY`.  There _may_ also be such for the `GROUP BY`.