# How to delete rows matching criteria from an enormous MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, database-indexes

I am using MySQL database in one of my applications in which a table's size is around 10GB. I want to delete rows from this table matching the criteria. Delete query is of the form :

```
Delete from table_name
where (a,b,c) in ((1,2,3),(1,5,6));
```

There is a composite index on the fields (a,b,c). The query takes several minutes to delete rows whereas I want the operation to be done in milliseconds or few seconds. How can I achieve this? Will the individual index on the fields be faster than the multiple-column index?

What I mean is if the query is like:

```
Delete from table_name
where a = 1 and (b,c) in ((2,3),(5,6));
```

Will this give faster results?

Comment: how you obtain the tuple in "in" clause .. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to pass between 5,000 to 100,000 values in mysql WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659553/correct-way-to-pass-between-5-000-to-100-000-values-in-mysql-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a distinct set of values for (a,b,c) you could partition the table on those values. [List Columns Partitioning.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-columns-list.html)  After the table was partitioned then "deleting" would instead be dropping the partitions, and would be very fast.

> MySQL 5.7 provides support for LIST COLUMNS partitioning. This is a variant of LIST partitioning that enables the use of multiple columns as partition keys, and for columns of data types other than integer types to be used as partitioning columns;

example table from documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE customers_1 (
   first_name VARCHAR(25),
   last_name VARCHAR(25),
   street_1 VARCHAR(30),
   street_2 VARCHAR(30),
   city VARCHAR(15),
   renewal DATE
)
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(city) (
   PARTITION pRegion_1 VALUES IN('Oskarshamn', 'Högsby', 'Mönsterås'),
   PARTITION pRegion_2 VALUES IN('Vimmerby', 'Hultsfred', 'Västervik'),
   PARTITION pRegion_3 VALUES IN('Nässjö', 'Eksjö', 'Vetlanda'),
   PARTITION pRegion_4 VALUES IN('Uppvidinge', 'Alvesta', 'Växjo')
);
```

I could not find an example in the documentation using the multiple columns as the partition key, but as you might expect it would look like...

```
CREATE TABLE customers_2 (
    first_name VARCHAR(25),
    last_name VARCHAR(25),
    street_1 VARCHAR(30),
    street_2 VARCHAR(30),
    city VARCHAR(15),
    renewal DATE
)
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(first_name,last_name) (
    PARTITION me_partition VALUES IN(('Alden','W'),('Aldino','W')),
    PARTITION you_partition VALUES IN(('Pooja','Gupta'),('PJ','Gupta'))
);
```

To partition the table you can use a bit of fancy pants dynamic sql.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000000;
SET @i = 0;
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE customers_2
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(first_name,last_name) (
    ',GROUP_CONCAT('PARTITION partition_',@i:=@i+1,' VALUES 
IN((''',d.first_name,''',''',d.last_name,'''))' SEPARATOR 
',\n\t'),'
);')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name
    FROM customers_2
) d;
```

This build the following alter statement

```
ALTER TABLE customers_2
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(first_name,last_name) (
    PARTITION partition_1 VALUES IN(('Alden','W')),
    PARTITION partition_2 VALUES IN(('Jon','Smith')),
    PARTITION partition_3 VALUES IN(('Other','Name')),
    ...
);
```